# Make rounded dialog in android?

Tags: android, listview, dialog

How to create rounded dialog in android like the given image below:
[image]

can any one help me how to make menu as shown an image.

Comment: Show us your efforts.

Comment: I guess one thing you can do is create a custom dialog with a transparent background, and give him in extra coordinate to place it where you want.

Comment: @Raghav Sood Sir I contacted you but haven't got any reply. Please help I have some queries.

Comment: This is background image, and this is possible in iphone because all iphone device has same height and width , tough in android

Comment: Nikhil i create customs dialog for this. i do try on it but can't get any helpful result. if you don't give correct answer then don't make the question to negative side.

Comment: this is android image not iphone. and i also try the methods of Damien R but it can't help me.

Comment: Heyy, you can create this using relevant images in xml and then you can use Popupview to display this layout. This is just an idea. But you can definitely achieve your view with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Satellite Menu" or "Arc Menu".

You can find sample at **[GitHub](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu)** to create such view. You can create a custom dialog to do so.